# create function with unknown parameter

Tags: r

I would like to know if it's possible to use a fonction with a parameter:

for example I have a matrix M=c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7)

using library(expm)

M2=expm(M*t)

without determining t, so I will get results as e2*t

Comment: Look at the Ryacas package.

Comment: The short answer is no. R is not a computer algebra system (that is, by default, but see for example G.Grothendieck's comment). You can however define a `function` that takes `t` as an argument, and then work with that.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thank you i will check that

Comment: @MauritsEvers alright thank you